# Why hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access and hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create_access are not fired?

Tags: nodes, 9

I'm implementing for nodes `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access()` and `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create_access()` for a project and they are not fired even after cleaning the cache many times. I checked the code and there is nothing wrong and there is any message in the logs and I'm logged as Administrator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is be logged as Administrator, this is because for determining access rights for an existing node, `\Drupal\node\NodeAccessControlHandler` first checks whether the user has the `bypass node access` permission. Such users have unrestricted access to all nodes and user 1 will always pass this check. And never will go to all implementations of `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access()` and `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create_access()` that are called later.