# How can I control node access based on entity reference to multiple users

Tags: nodes, 9, security

I have multiple uses for this functionality now but mainly for a private message system.

What I want to do:

- Configure a content type with an entity reference to users
- Create nodes of that type and select multiple users using the entity reference field
- Limit visibility of each node of that type to the users selected in that field

I believe there was a module for this in D7, though I can't find it now. But I've had no success finding one for D9.

Is there a module or set of modules anyone is aware of that could provide this kind of access control?

If a module was to be built, any suggestions for best way to approach it? (Is it a really bad idea to put some conditional logic in a template... "if logged in uid = one of values in field x, print, otherwise don't" ? (I don't know the twig syntax for that))

(Since I mentioned private messages, I'm aware of the D9 PM module. But for a lot of reasons, I'd rather just use nodes and comments system. The node+comment system is already well developed and the only thing missing really is multiple-user visibility control.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a bad idea to do this in templates as their output will be cached by default.

If it's just for viewing the full node via its canonical URL (`/node/123` or `/my-node-alias`) you can achieve that easily by implementing [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access/9.0.x) in a custom module.

```php
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access().
 */
function MYMODULE_node_access(EntityInterface $entity, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {

  // Check node type and operation.
  if ($entity->bundle() === 'article' && $operation === 'view') {

    $uids = [];
    // Get the allowed users.
    if ($users = $entity->get('field_users')->getValue()) {
      $uids = array_column($users, 'target_id', 'target_id');
    }
    // Add the node author.
    $uids[$entity->getOwnerId()] = $entity->getOwnerId();

    // Return "forbidden" if current user is not in that list.
    return AccessResult::forbiddenIf(!isset($uids[$account->id()]))
      ->cachePerUser()
      ->addCacheableDependency($entity);
  }

  // No opinion.
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

But note that this hook is **not called from Views** or entity queries for performance reasons and for proper functioning of the pager system. For that you need to implement a different access strategy, see [[Drupal API] Node access rights](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/group/node_access/9.0.x) and [[Question] Views Search Ignoring Custom Node Access permissions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/52756/15055).

Note also that [this hook is bypassed for user 1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/313694/15055) (if you during development wonder why breakpoints/`dump()` are ignored).

Comment: Much appreciated! The additional views info is also a huge help. On views: in practical terms that means users without access to the node will be able to see it in a view (unless the view is otherwise configured to hide those nodes)? But a node link in a view would still go through hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access if you click it. Am I right?

Comment: @aharown07 – Yes 

Comment: Maybe this should be a separate post, but the context here helps: Can anyone steer me toward a hook (or other method) that would be called from views? I'm using regular views access controls and block controls as a solution now, but I'm a little paranoid, so... what if some view breaks and links are visible to users who should not see them? So I'd like a layer that would do a similar access check on the link from views also.

Answer (score 0):

I added condition to give the node author access also, without including the author in the entity reference field:

```
<?php
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access().
 */
function MYMODULENAME_node_access(EntityInterface $entity, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {
  if ($entity->bundle() === 'pm' && $operation === 'view') {
    if ($users = $entity->get('MYFIELDNAME')->getValue()) {
      $uids = array_column($users, 'target_id', 'target_id');
      $author_id = $entity->getOwnerID();
      if (isset($uids[$account->id()]) || $author_id == $account->id()) {
        return AccessResult::neutral();
      }
    }
 return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe there's a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: Answer 2 seems obsolete after updates to Answer 1: at the moment, with Node View Permissions installed, the author of the node also has visibility when not listed in the entity reference field.