# Why doesn't the entity access handler I wrote work when the entity is referenced?

Tags: 8, entities

I have set a handler for the access of my entity but when I reference it in another entity, the access is not checked. I want the reference and the entity to have the same access check.
Any idea ?
The entity is a taxonomy term and I reference it in a basic node

The handler below, I return forbidden to test

```
/**
 * Defines the access control handler for the taxonomy term entity type.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term
 */
class MyAccessControlHandler extends TermAccessControlHandler {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function checkAccess(EntityInterface $entity, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }

}
```

Edit :
Until I found a better solution, I use view and form alter hook to check the referenced entity access by getting the said entity and using it's access() method

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! If there is some custom code you must add that to the question or the question will be downvoted. I wish to make to aware that Drupal 8 is end-of-life and is no longer developed or supported on drupal.org.

Comment: I have updated with the handler code

Comment: Drupal caches access results, causing access check code to not be hit. Clear caches or disable caching while debugging to eliminate this possibility.

Comment: Already done with drush cr

Comment: Is your `MyAccessControlHandler` class even getting called/instantiated? Do this [via a hook instead](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/313783/27710).

Comment: Access checks are not performed when adding an entity as a reference. I think you would instead need to put a constraint on the entity doing the referencing.

Comment: Wait, are you thinking the entity shouldn't be able to be added, or that when it is added, it should not be rendered?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Views Search Ignoring Custom Node Access permissions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52756/views-search-ignoring-custom-node-access-permissions)

Comment: Usually user 1 bypasses access rules. And views and other entity queries ignore them as well. Then you maybe need access grants.

Comment: @Jaypan . Yes I think that the referenced entity should not be viewed by someone who don't have that right on the entity

Comment: Access handlers are only on CRUD actions directly on the entity. If you are adding the entity as a reference, you need to put permissions on that field. The field permission module will probably help.