# How to programmatically grant access to view unpublished content with a special query string?

Tags: 9

In my application, I want anonymous users to be able to view an unpublished node but only if they append a special code to the URL.  For example:

```
www.mysite.com/node/123?code=Hx23ufG38
```

I figure I can do something in a preprocess function to check if the code is appended to the URL and, if so, allow the user to view the unpublished node.  (This clearly is not for a use case where the content is sensitive, because anyone visiting the page at the URL with the code appended will be able to see the page.)

How can I programmatically grant the current (anonymous) user permission to view unpublished content, provided the condition is met in the URL?

This is for a Drupal 9 website.

Comment: Broad strokes you'd probably use `hook_entity_access` (or `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access`), and add a query string cache context to the `AccessResult` you return from there

Comment: I suspect that is the right answer.  I'm experimenting with that hook and it appears to do precisely what I need.

Comment: Little bit similar to this maybe https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/313783/15055

Comment: Yes, but then you need to add `->addCacheContexts(['url.query_args:code'])`. Otherwise the first anonymous user with query string will grant access for all other anonymous users following.

Comment: @4uk4 – Ah and in the given answer I actually need to add the user cache context?

Comment: @leymannx, cachePerUser() is a shortcut for the user context.

Comment: @4uk4 – Ah of course!! 

Comment: @4uk4 -- "first anonymous user with query string will grant access for all other anonymous users".  I can't reproduce that issue in my application, initially. I have caching turned on at admin/config/development/performance but even with just `return AccessResult::allowed();` and no cache context, access by one anonymous user doesn't clear the way for others.

Comment: This cache setting is only for the headers sent out to the browser. Drupal has two page cache modules. The anonymous page cache varies by the entire URL including query string, the dynamic page cache varies by route and contexts. As long as the anonymous page cache has cached the correct results all things are fine, but starting with a cleared cache certain combinations of node request should reproduce wrong answers.

Comment: Have you considered using the [Access unpublished](https://www.drupal.org/project/access_unpublished) contrib module?

Comment: @NoSssweat Good idea, but that module doesn't allow for anonymous previews of revisions, which is a requirement in my case: https://www.drupal.org/project/access_unpublished/issues/3207620

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/access_unpublished or look at its code.